# Find definition in Julia

Tags: visual-studio-code, julia

```
using CALIPSO

# problem
objective(x) = x[1]
equality(x) = [x[1]^2 - x[2] - 1.0; x[1] - x[3] - 0.5]
cone(x) = x[2:3]

# variables 
num_variables = 3

# solver
solver = Solver(objective, equality, cone, num_variables);

# initialize
x0 = [-2.0, 3.0, 1.0]
initialize!(solver, x0)

# solve 
solve!(solver)

# solution 
solver.solution.variables # x* = [1.0, 0.0, 0.5]
```

How do I find the "Solver" definition? I am working with this open source package: https://github.com/thowell/CALIPSO.jl

In Pycharm / Python, I can just press Go to Definition. In VSCode / Julia, Go -> Go to Definition is grayed out.

Searching the text is horrible, there are many "Solver" texts inside the CALIPSO package. It is impossible to crawl through 100s of results.

Comment: Make sure to read about functions and composite types in Julia. then you will find out investigate which part of the source code.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't have the julia plugin installed in VSCode yet. VSCode didn't create any warning that that was the case.